# Verify existence of street address against OpenStreetMap database in python

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I have an application in python which parses pages of text for street addresses.  I would like to verify these are actual addresses and thought of checking them against the OpenStreetMap database.  Is this possible through the osmapi?  If so could you point me to some documentation?  Everything I have found just deals with latitute and longitude.  If not, is there another tool that could get the job done?

Example:

application finds address 4837 Jjjjjj Ct Jujube, NE ideally I would like to check this against OpenStreetMap and get an indication that it does not exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [list of search engines](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) (geocoders) in the OSM wiki. But before running heavy queries on them be sure to read their terms of services / usage policies carefully.

Also keep in mind that addresses in OSM aren't complete, which applies for every map database. Ideally you should run your query through multiple geocoders to see if any of them returns a match.